# Creating a Bandwidth Pool with PHP

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a new bandwidth pool using PHP but I am getting back an error about my API key. If I run any other scripts however with the same key they return just fine which makes me think something in my script is causing things to get parsed out of order:

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
$apiUsername = getenv('SOFTLAYER_USERNAME');
$apiKey = getenv('SOFTLAYER_API_KEY');


$template = new stdClass();
$template->accountId = xxxxx;
$template->bandwidthAllotmentTypeId  = 2;
$template->locationGroupId = 1;
$template->name  = 'newBWpoolPHP';
$template->serviceProviderId = 1;

try {
  $client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment', $apiUsername, $apiKey);
  $response = $client->createObject(template);

  print_r($response);

 } catch(Exception $e) {
     echo 'Cannot compute. Error is: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to you are creating wrong the service, It requires the following:

getClient('serviceName', ObjectID, Username, ApiKey)

In this case there is no a ObjectID, so you need to send the value as null.

try the code below:

```
<?php
    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
    $apiUsername = getenv('SOFTLAYER_USERNAME');
    $apiKey = getenv('SOFTLAYER_API_KEY');

    $template = new stdClass();
    $template->accountId = 307608;
    $template->bandwidthAllotmentTypeId  = 2;
    $template->locationGroupId = 1;
    $template->name  = 'newBWpoolPHP';

    try {
      $client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Network_Bandwidth_Version1_Allotment', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
      $response = $client->createObject($template);

      print_r($response);

     } catch(Exception $e) {
         echo 'Cannot compute. Error is: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```